# How to setup local server on Linux for testing Dokku?

Tags: linux, docker, git, nginx, heroku

I'm new to **Dokku** and **nginx** server and I'm trying to set up server locally on **Linux Ubuntu 20.04** for testing purpose instead of using one such as **Hetzner (Cloud)** or DigitalOcean (which already contains [Dokku image](https://marketplace.digitalocean.com/apps/dokku) which is older version of Dokku than the one I need) which could cause unwanted financial expenses.

More precisely is I'm trying to setup domain address in my `/etc/hosts` file, e.g. (**updated** this with `dokku.me` domain):

```
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    
    188.x.xx.xxx    domain.com

    10.0.0.2        dokku.me
```

By following this [Dokku setup tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-your-on-heroku-with-dokku/) and passed it one of following commands:

```
$ dokku domains:set-global localhost
$ dokku domains:set-global domain.com
```

But once I execute following command (in order to show created `djangotutorial` app):

```
$ dokku config:show djangotutorial
```

... I get this as output:

```
=====> djangotutorial env vars
NO_VHOST:  1
```

From there everything I execute normally in mentioned tutorial until I execute following command (to push to remote server):

```
$ git push dokku main
```

... I get following message:

```
ssh: connect to host domain.com port 22: Connection timed out 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

**UPDATE#1**

Output of `host domain.com`:

```
domain.com has address 188.x.xx.xxx
domain.com mail is handled by 10 mx.domain.com.
```

Output of `ping -c 10 domain.com`:

```
PING domain.com (188.x.xx.xxx) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from domain.com (188.x.xx.xxx): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=17.4 ms
64 bytes from domain.com (188.x.xx.xxx): icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=9.22 ms
64 bytes from domain.com (188.x.xx.xxx): icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=1.88 ms
64 bytes from domain.com (188.x.xx.xxx): icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=4.12 ms
64 bytes from domain.com (188.x.xx.xxx): icmp_seq=5 ttl=63 time=1.87 ms
64 bytes from domain.com (188.x.xx.xxx): icmp_seq=6 ttl=63 time=1.43 ms
64 bytes from domain.com (188.x.xx.xxx): icmp_seq=7 ttl=63 time=2.77 ms
64 bytes from domain.com (188.x.xx.xxx): icmp_seq=8 ttl=63 time=3.60 ms
64 bytes from domain.com (188.x.xx.xxx): icmp_seq=9 ttl=63 time=2.06 ms
64 bytes from domain.com (188.x.xx.xxx): icmp_seq=10 ttl=63 time=3.95 ms
```

Output of `traceroute domain.com` command:

```
traceroute to domain.com (188.x.xx.xxx), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  router.lan (192.168.ab.x)  7.239 ms  7.141 ms  7.148 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Outpt `ip addr` command:

```
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4c:ed:fb:95:d2:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlx048d3814ce5c: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:8d:38:14:ce:5c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.ab.xyz/24 brd 192.168.ab.qyy scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlx048d3814ce5c
       valid_lft 4694sec preferred_lft 4694sec
    inet6 fe80::888c:74c6:b7d7:2de0/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: br-cac2c9a0fe00: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:23:36:d3:17 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-cac2c9a0fe00
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:23ff:fe36:d317/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:f3:02:02:63 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:f3ff:fe02:263/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: veth374c258@if6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-cac2c9a0fe00 state UP group default 
    link/ether 46:ca:a7:33:95:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::44ca:a7ff:fe33:950f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: veth264cbc8@if8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default 
    link/ether 66:1d:5e:0e:05:96 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::641d:5eff:fe0e:596/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: vethad55888@if10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-cac2c9a0fe00 state UP group default 
    link/ether 9e:80:5a:9c:a0:33 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 2
    inet6 fe80::9c80:5aff:fe9c:a033/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
13: veth1584b7e@if12: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-cac2c9a0fe00 state UP group default 
    link/ether c2:53:b9:e6:02:3d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 3
    inet6 fe80::c053:b9ff:fee6:23d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
14: vboxnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
15: vboxnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
16: vboxnet2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
17: vboxnet3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
18: vboxnet4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:04 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.1/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global vboxnet4
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::800:27ff:fe00:4/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

dsfsdf
```

Output of `route` command:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         router.lan      0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlx048d3814ce5c
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vboxnet4
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlx048d3814ce5c
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-cac2c9a0fe00
192.168.ab.t    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlx048d3814ce5c
```

**NOTE**: I've used aliases for certain IP addresses such as `188.x.xx.xxx`, `192.168.ab.t`, etc.

=============== **UPDATE#1::END** ==============

Is there a way to achieve this and how by mentioned info?

Any advice/help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Connection timed out` means that the address, to which `domain.com` is resolved, is either nonexistent or the host is not running, or that packets to or from this address get dropped somewhere in your network. If the host was running and reachable but with no SSH server active you would normally get a `Connection refused`. If your system would not know how to reach the address I would expect `No route to host`. Please [edit] your question and show the output of `host domain.com`, `ping -c 10 domain.com`, `traceroute domain.com`, `ip addr` and `route` and add details about your network.

Comment: Updated my OP with suggested commands outputs, please take a look. Regarding details about my network: Is this sufficient info that I've provided and if not **what exactly** else is needed?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add details about your network. How is your local host connected to `domain.com`? What I can see from the added information: `ping` works. `router.lan` is your default route, there is no specific route for `188.x.xx.xxx`. Is the default route the expected route for `domain.com`? `traceroute` ends at `router.lan`. So either this router or something behind it seems to drop some packets to/from `188.x.xx.xxx`, namely packets sent to the SSH port 22 and packets sent by `traceroute` or their response. Is there any packet filtering, firewall or NAT between `router.lan` and `domain.com`?

Comment: ... If the route via `router.lan` is the expected one, does the router know how to reach `188.x.xx.xxx`? Is the configuration of the router correct?

Comment: Route, i.e. IP address, set for `domain.com` is actually my **public** IP address (which I get when I google "what is my IP"). I don't think anything is between `router.lan` and `domain.com` since everything is being run on local machine which is part of other networked machines in company but that should NOT be problem since it's targeting itself, right?  

Which specific info is needed as details of my network (i.e. which **specific Linux command**)?

Comment: **Please [edit] your question to add requested information.** Describing the network means telling details about the structure of your network, e.g. draw a diagram on paper or some ASCII graphics in a code block. What physical and/or virtual hosts do you have? What internal and external IP addresses do they have? How are they connected? On which host do you run the `git push ...` command? Which host are you trying to reach? The router may block attempts to reach the external IP address from the internal network, or maybe you did not correctly configure port forwarding in your router.

Comment: I would love to do that, but I'm not permitted to do expose such information due to its sensitive nature and I'm referring to (complete) network structure (as I've already mentioned it company's network). Anyway, thank you for your help and suggestions. ;)

Comment: Without enough information it is difficult to provide specific help. In this case you should ask your network administrator for help.